# Powershell - add column to end of CSV

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, export

I found a powershell script this morning that will add the date created to each line in CSV. I got it do do almost exactly what I need, but I want the addition to be at the end of each line, not at the start. Can someone help please?

This one works, but it's the wrong order

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt -Exclude merged.csv -PipelineVariable csv |
  ForEach-Object FullName | # parameter binding problem otherwise...
  Import-Csv |
  Select-Object @{n='Timestamp';e={$csv.LastWriteTime.ToString('d')}} , * |
  Export-Csv -NTI merged.csv
```

I tried to add -Indexed but either it's in the wrong place or I need to actually index the objects? Which I don't understand how to do.

Does not work

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt -Exclude merged.csv -PipelineVariable csv |
  ForEach-Object FullName | # parameter binding problem otherwise...
  Import-Csv |
  Select-Object -Index (n-1), ($a.count - 1) @{n='Timestamp';e={$csv.LastWriteTime.ToString('s')}} , * |
  Export-Csv -NTI merged.csv
```

Comment: on your first snippet, just change the position of the asterisk :P `*, @{ N=.....`

Answer (score 0):

`Select-Object` is adding the new column at the beginning, first import the CSV file and then add the new column.

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt -Exclude merged.csv -PipelineVariable csv |
ForEach-Object FullName | # parameter binding problem otherwise...
Import-Csv |
ForEach-Object { Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Timestamp' -NotePropertyValue $csv.LastWriteTime.ToString('d') -PassThru } |
Export-Csv -NTI merged.csv
```

Try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Im glad it worked for you, please accept it as the solution so that others may find it easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt -Exclude merged.csv -PipelineVariable csv |
ForEach-Object FullName | # parameter binding problem otherwise...
Import-Csv |
ForEach-Object { Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Timestamp' -NotePropertyValue $csv.LastWriteTime.ToString('d') -PassThru } |
Export-Csv -NTI merged.csv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).